# Jquery ajax with form serialize is not calling action class. its appending %5B0%5D in the datastring

Tags: jquery, ajax

In my action class, I have a list of complex object is there.
From Jsp, I am trying to serialize the form and send. 
But it's not calling the action class, and error is thrown from server side. As the form element names contain [].

the serialized value is

> entitlement.organizationId=2801&entitlement.organizationName=asjaj&entitlement.productNumber=pr1&entitlement.productName=QC&entitlement.productType=&entitlement.eon=sd&entitlement.entitlementType=DEV&entitlement.entitlementStatus=AVAIL&entitlement.effectiveDate=02-04-2016&entitlement.expirationDate=02-04-2016&entitlement.entitlementQuantity=122&entitlement.productActivationCode=gggg&entitlement.supportEndDate=02-19-2016&entitlement.quantityUnderSupport=&entitlement.entitlementIdExt=&entitlement.saidList%5B0%5D.saId=aaa&entitlement.saidList%5B0%5D.startDate=02-16-2016&entitlement.saidList%5B0%5D.endDate=02-24-2016&entitlement.saidList%5B0%5D.quantityUnderSupport=555&entitlement.saidList%5B0%5D.externalSAID=&entitlement.saidList%5B0%5D.endDate=&entitlement.saidList%5B0%5D.endDate=&entitlement.saidList%5B0%5D.endDate=

Please help..I am stuck for 2 days..

From my javascript.

```
var dataString =  $("form").serialize();                         
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "EntitlementAction_submitNewEntitlement",
    data: dataString,
    traditional: true,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result);
        $("#summaryreport").html(result);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        //alert('<s:property value="%{getText(\'config.alert45\')}" />');
    }
});
```

In eclipse debug mode, the control is not going to action class

Comment: Please edit your post so it's better readable. And what have you tried so far? What errors occur?

Comment: I am using struts with jquery.. From  my jsp, i am rows dynamically.then ajax post the entire form to action class.. its not populating value in action class and its not going action class method in debug mode

Comment: var dataString =  $("form").serialize();       $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: "EntitlementAction_submitNewEntitlement",
              data: dataString,     
              traditional: true,
              async: false,                 
       cache: false,            
              success: function(result) {
               alert(result);
               $("#summaryreport").html(result);
        },
           error: function(error) {    
          //alert('<s:property value="%{getText(\'config.alert45\')}" />');
            }
      });

Comment: Without looking on configuration files and/or source code it's impossible to help.